# Filtering by map's key & value using JPA2

Tags: jpa, dictionary

For the entity defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Acl implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "acl_id")
private Long id;

@ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "acl_permits")
private Map<String, Integer> permits = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Query:

```
query = em.createQuery("select a FROM Acl a " +
"JOIN a.permits p WITH KEY(p) = '" + user + "' and VALUE(p) = " + permit + "");
```

is converted to:

```
select acl0_.acl_id as acl1_1_ from Acl acl0_ 
inner join acl_permits permits1_ on acl0_.acl_id=permits1_.Acl_acl_id 
and (permits1_.permits_KEY='user1' 
and (select permits1_.permits from acl_permits permits1_ where acl0_.acl_id=permits1_.Acl_acl_id)=1)
```

What would be the query in order to get it converted into?:

```
select acl0_.acl_id as acl1_1_ from Acl acl0_ 
inner join acl_permits permits1_ on acl0_.acl_id=permits1_.Acl_acl_id 
and (permits1_.permits_KEY='user1' and acl0_.acl_id=permits1_.Acl_acl_id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use native SQL in JPA.  So you can do this instead.

```
query = em.createNativeQuery("select acl0_.acl_id as acl1_1_ from Acl acl0_ 
    inner join acl_permits permits1_ on acl0_.acl_id=permits1_.Acl_acl_id 
    and (permits1_.permits_KEY=?user and acl0_.acl_id=permits1_.Acl_acl_id=?permit_id)");
```

Comment: Yeah, so far that looks as the easiest option. Though, let's still wait if JPA2/Hibernate gurus would give an answer.

Comment: It might be possible to do with Hibernate, but if you *need* really strict control over SQL generated then you should use native queries.  After all, the queries could change at any time if they're generated.